# Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugKotlin'. Ошибка сборки Kotlin-проекта

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, kotlin

Пытаюсь скомпилировать приложение на Kotlin. До определенного момента все компилировалось нормально, но потом начала выскакивать ошибкаExecution failed for task ':app:compileDebugKotlin'

Вот логи:

```
Information:Gradle tasks [:app:generateDebugSources, :app:generateDebugAndroidTestSources, :app:compileDebugSources, :app:compileDebugAndroidTestSources]
:app:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:checkDebugManifest
:app:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportAppcompatV72310Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportCardviewV72310Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportRecyclerviewV72310Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportV42310Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComMelnykovFloatingactionbutton130Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareMeDrakeetMaterialdialogLibrary128Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareNetGrandcentrixTrayTray100Rc1Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareDebugDependencies
:app:compileDebugAidl UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:app:mergeDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:mergeDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:processDebugManifest UP-TO-DATE
:app:processDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugSources UP-TO-DATE
:app:preDebugAndroidTestBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportTestEspressoEspressoCore20Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportTestEspressoEspressoIdlingResource20Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportTestTestingSupportLib01Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareDebugAndroidTestDependencies
:app:compileDebugAndroidTestAidl UP-TO-DATE
:app:processDebugAndroidTestManifest UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugAndroidTestRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugAndroidTestBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugAndroidTestAssets UP-TO-DATE
:app:mergeDebugAndroidTestAssets UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugAndroidTestResValues UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugAndroidTestResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:mergeDebugAndroidTestResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:processDebugAndroidTestResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugAndroidTestSources UP-TO-DATE
:app:processDebugJavaRes UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugKotlin
D:\Mahach\AndroidDeveloment\workspace\Notelin\app\src\main\java\imangazaliev\notelin\MainActivity.kt
Error:(38, 33) Unresolved reference: activity_main
Error:(89, 37) Unresolved reference: main
Error:(91, 52) Unresolved reference: action_search
Error:(93, 43) Unresolved reference: OnQueryTextListener
Error:(102, 18) Unresolved reference: menuDeleteAllNotes
Error:(106, 18) Unresolved reference: menuSortByName
Error:(112, 18) Unresolved reference: menuSortByDate
Error:(193, 59) Unresolved reference: note_info_dialog
Error:(194, 42) Unresolved reference: tvNoteInfo
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugKotlin'.
> Compilation error. See log for more details
Information:BUILD FAILED
Information:Total time: 3.186 secs
Information:10 errors
Information:0 warnings
Information:See complete output in console
```

А вот **build.gradle**:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'

buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.0.0-beta-4584'
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-android-extensions:$kotlin_version"
    }
}
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        resValue "string", "tray__authority", "${applicationId}.tray"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    sourceSets {
        main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test:testing-support-lib:0.1'
    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.0'

    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:$kotlin_version"
    compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.0"
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.1.0'
    compile 'com.michaelpardo:activeandroid:3.1.0-SNAPSHOT'
    compile 'net.grandcentrix.tray:tray:1.0.0-rc1'
    compile 'com.melnykov:floatingactionbutton:1.3.0'
    compile 'me.drakeet.materialdialog:library:1.2.8'

}
```

Comment: Вот этот файл `src\main\java\imangazaliev\notelin\MainActivity.kt` еще покажите, пожалуйста.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Нужно добавить `apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'` в build.gradle вашего модуля

Comment: В beta этого плагина еще не существовало, он только в RC появился. 
http://blog.jetbrains.com/kotlin/2016/02/kotlin-1-0-release-candidate-is-out/

Ответ не соответствует вопросу.

Comment: Мм, не знаю, но мне помогло